# Converting JFormattedTextField.getText() return result into a custom type

Tags: java, string, swing, oop, jformattedtextfield

So I'm fairly new to Java Swing and graphical interface framework and I'm trying to get user input and use my custom constructor to instantiate new objects referred to here as 'formation' (let's call it a mother class). (C is an instance of a 'Grand mother' Class) and (Matiére Matiére or M is an instance of 'daughter 'class this notation might be confusing but **these classes DO NOT extend each other but require an arguement of the "descendant" class to construct a new instance**) so (C<-F<-M) and my `JFrame` takes into it's constructor parameter an instance C of type 'Centre de formation'.

I've Float parsed and cast most of the needed arguments but the final argument is in itself a class 'Matiére" and obviously it's not possible to cast from the `JFormattedTextField.getText()` return type `String` directly into Matiére (which in itself has a rather detailed constructor) .

My question is (albeit might be of a beginner) how do convert `JFormattedTextField.getText()` return result into a custom type of my choice? *Since casting is off the table*, is there another method to construct this 'formation'?

Is there a way to trace everything back to `ObjectType` then I can do the down boxing that I desire?

Here's the code:

```
 bouton_f0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (!bouton_f0.getModel().isPressed()) {
             {  /*ajouter formation*/
                 JFrame f = new JFrame("Ajout d'une formation");
                    f.setSize(500, 200);
                    JPanel pannel = new JPanel();
                    JTextField  testField1 = new JTextField ("nom formation");
                    String nom = testField1.getText();
                    JTextField  testField2 = new JTextField ("duree formation");
                    float duree =Float.parseFloat(testField2.getText()) ;
                    JTextField  testField3 = new JTextField ("prix formation");
                    float prix =Float.parseFloat(testField2.getText()) ;
                    JTextField  testField4 = new JTextField ("Matiére initiale");
                    String Matiére = testField1.getText();
                    /*Cannot cast String  to Matiére to put in the following constructor */ 
                    formation R = new formation(nom,duree,prix,Matiére);
                    
                    C.ajouter_forma(R);
                    pannel.add(testField1);pannel.add(testField2);
                    pannel.add(testField3);pannel.add(testField4);
                    f.getContentPane().add(pannel);
                    f.setVisible(true);
        
                 /*textArea = new JTextArea("nom formation",5, 20);
                 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
                 textArea.setEditable(false); */

                 panneau.removeAll();
                 panneau.revalidate();
                 panneau.repaint();
                 
                 setContentPane(p_forma);
                 setSize(600,150);
                 setVisible(true); 
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Casting is not possible in this case. What you can do though, is to create a new class named `Matiere` and create an instance of it, using the input provided by `JTextField`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: There is not a single `JFormattedTextField` in your example code, so it’s not clear why you are talking about `JFormattedTextField` all the time. The class `JFormattedTextField` *has* a `getValue()` method which can return an object of the right type when you use an appropriate formatter. However, you are clearly initializing your text fields with strings not being numbers (`"nom formation"`, `"duree formation"`), immediately followed by trying to parse the same text with `Float.parseFloat(…)`. How is that supposed to work?